# I want to customize convert lead page

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

[image]

When I click on convert lead button this page opens. This is standard functionality. I want that instead of radio check box being selected on create new by default it should be on choose existing by default when I click convert lead. Any suggestions on how this can be achieved exactly?

Comment: see [Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GddMaUAJ/ability-to-customize-lead-conversion-page-to-add-fields-and-make-fields-required)